# Drop all columns from data frame except index and nth

Tags: pandas

I have a variable size columned data frame. What is the best way to drop, in-place, all columns except for the nth and the index column.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just keep the n-th by indexing it explicitly

```
df = df[df.columns[n:n+1]]
```

note range notation to make sure you get a dataframe not a series

the index column will naturally stay in df